# vscode html tag color is red when writing vue.js code

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

When writing vue.js code, html tag color is red. Can I change this color into other color like blue?
[image: this is vscode screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. I just disabled Material Theme.